# heap-use-after-free on leetcode binary tree traversal

Tags: c, binary-tree, realloc

It runs ok in my Xcode so can anyone tell me what's the problem?

I tested and the problem is in reallocing space for stack but I don't understand the error..
The test case is [1,null,2,3] so 1 is root, 2 is 1's right child, 3 is 2's left child. The solution should return the array [1,2,3].

```
 /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     struct TreeNode *left;
 *     struct TreeNode *right;
 * };
 *
 **
 * Return an array of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */

struct TreeNode* cercaRoot(struct TreeNode* root, struct TreeNode** stack, int* stackSize){
    if (root->left){

    *stackSize += 1;
    stack = realloc(stack, (*stackSize)*sizeof(struct TreeNode*));
    stack[*stackSize-1] = root;

    return root->left;

    } else if (root->right){
        return root->right;
    } else{
        while(*stackSize){
            root = stack[*stackSize-1];
            if (root->right) {
                *stackSize -= 1;
                stack = realloc(stack, (*stackSize)*sizeof(struct TreeNode*));

                return root->right;
            } else {
                *stackSize -= 1;
                stack = realloc(stack, (*stackSize)*sizeof(struct TreeNode*));
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

int* preorderTraversal(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize) {
    *returnSize = 0;
    if (root==NULL) return NULL;

    int* array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
    array[0]=root->val;
    *returnSize += 1;

    int stackSize = 0;

    struct TreeNode** stack = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TreeNode*));

    root = cercaRoot(root, stack, &stackSize);

    while (root){
        array = realloc(array, (*returnSize+1)*sizeof(int));
        array[*returnSize]=root->val;
        *returnSize+=1;

        root = cercaRoot(root, stack, &stackSize);
    }

    //free(stack);

    return array;

}
```

Comment: first things first, it's better to not do this: if (root->left). Always check if a pointer == or != NULL. Also always check pointers before de-referencing them i.e. *stackSize += 1.

Comment: Nothing wrong with `if (root -> left)`; it's perfectly well-defined in C. `!= NULL` is just noise. Checking for `stackSize` being null also seems silly here — you can assert it if you really must, but it's an obvious precondition to the function. That being said, have you tried running valgrind on this?

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 yeh that's true, but I've had issues with not explicitly comparing to the implementation-defined NULL.

Comment: @Medicineman25 That strongly points to a non-conformant implementation. In any standards-compliant implementation (and in fact, in literally any implementation I've ever seen), `NULL` is defined as zero (with all of the standard's comments and caveats regarding the use of zero as a pointer value), and `if` is defined to check for non-zero, meaning that `if (p)` and `if (p != NULL)` are identical (assuming that `p` is a pointer in the first place).

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 huh... good to know!! I'm just trying to remember exactly where it was I had issues. I think it was when using arm-none-eabi-gcc, but tbh I can't be sure. I'll definitely keep this in mind. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting any error with this code

Output is:

> ret[0] = 1
>
> ret[1] = 2
>
> ret[2] = 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TreeNode {
      int val;
      struct TreeNode *left;
      struct TreeNode *right;
 };



 /*
 **
 * Return an array of size *returnSize.
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */

struct TreeNode* cercaRoot(struct TreeNode* root, struct TreeNode** stack, int* stackSize){
    if (root->left){

    *stackSize += 1;
   stack = realloc(stack, (*stackSize)*sizeof(struct TreeNode*));
   stack[*stackSize-1] = root;

return root->left;

} else if (root->right){
    return root->right;
} else{
    while(*stackSize){
        root = stack[*stackSize-1];
        if (root->right) {
            *stackSize -= 1;
            stack = realloc(stack, (*stackSize)*sizeof(struct TreeNode*));

            return root->right;
        } else {
            *stackSize -= 1;
            stack = realloc(stack, (*stackSize)*sizeof(struct TreeNode*));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
    }
}

int* preorderTraversal(struct TreeNode* root, int* returnSize) {
*returnSize = 0;
if (root==NULL) return NULL;

int* array = calloc(1, sizeof(int));
array[0]=root->val;
*returnSize += 1;

int stackSize = 0;

struct TreeNode** stack = calloc(1, sizeof(struct TreeNode*));

root = cercaRoot(root, stack, &stackSize);

while (root){
    array = realloc(array, (*returnSize+1)*sizeof(int));
    array[*returnSize]=root->val;
    *returnSize+=1;

    root = cercaRoot(root, stack, &stackSize);
}

free(stack);

return array;

}

struct TreeNode* nodeRoot;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

int stackSize = 0;
int returnSize = 0;

nodeRoot = malloc(sizeof(nodeRoot));

struct TreeNode* nodeLeft = malloc(sizeof(nodeLeft));
struct TreeNode* nodeRight = malloc(sizeof(nodeRight));

nodeRoot->left = nodeLeft;
nodeRoot->right = nodeRight;

nodeRoot->val = 1;
nodeRoot->left = NULL;
nodeRoot->right->val = 2;
nodeRoot->right->left = malloc(sizeof(nodeLeft));
nodeRoot->right->left->val = 3;

int* ret = preorderTraversal(nodeRoot, &returnSize);

if(ret != NULL){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("ret[i] = %d\n",ret[i]);                   
    }

}

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

If I use sizeof(ret) in the for loop then I get:

> ret[0] = 1
>
> ret[1] = 2
>
> ret[2] = 3
>
> ret[3] = 0
>
> ret[4] = 0
>
> ret[5] = 0
>
> ret[6] = 33
>
> ret[7] = 0

Which is expected given the number of valid nodes assigned to the array.

Anyway, the logic seems fine. My first question would be how are you declaring your test case?

Comment: Actually it’s the default test case on leetcode, in Xcode I just mallocd 3 treenodes and linked them together, pretty much as you did in your main..

Comment: "pretty much" as I did or EXACTLY as I did? This could be a dangling pointer issue i.e. you haven't allocated NULL to the unused child and iterating is causing an error. I would suggest copy-pasting my code, it should compile as-is. If it's not that and you have tied up all your loose ends, and my code doesn't compile on your system then it's onto the next questions: what system is it running in where the error occurs, also what is the error? Is this compiling in XCode but then not in Linux? Have you installed all the correct tools?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/data-structure-tree/134/traverse-a-tree/928/ This is where I get the error even with your code, in my main the code works just fine

Comment: Ok I can't access that link. You'll need to edit your answer and provide the exact error output. Before doing that, I would suggest setting breakpoints and stepping through the code one line at a time, that way you can see exactly when the values are not being set correctly.